# How to remove any unicode repeating letter?

Tags: python, string, unicode

In english, sometimes you have repeating letter like this :
`hello my hero hhhhhhhhhhh` that's for `h`, but I want to remove all kinds of letters repeating like this 2 or more times and replace them with a space in unicode letter. I have arabic here. I only have one letter I can remove, this is my code:

```
#remove laughing
def remove_laughs(self, text):       
    text=re.sub("ه{2,}", "", text)
    return text
```

Comment: Would you expect the same to happen in mississippi? misisipi just doesn't have the same ring to it..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
from itertools import groupby

def remove_dups(s):
    replace_with = ' '
    return ''.join([x if sum(1 for i in y)<2 else replace_with for x,y in groupby(s)])
```

Answer (score 0):

any duplicated character

```
import re
re.sub(r'(.)\1+', ' ', 'مرحبا هههههههههه')
# 'مرحبا  '
```

---

only letter characters

```
import regex
regex.sub(r'(\pL)\1+', ' ', 'مرحبا هههههههههه')
```

Comment: This eliminates any kind of repeated characters (eg. punctuation, digits), not only letters.