# How can I use regex to search unicode texts and find words that contain repeated alphabets?

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have dataset which contains comments of people in Persian and Arabic. Some comments contain words like `عاااالی` which is not a real word and the right word is actually `عالی`. It's like using `woooooooow!` instead of `WoW!`.

My intention is to find these words and remove all extra alphabets. the only refrence I found is the code below which removes the words with repeated alphabets:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\s*\b(?=[a-z\d]*([a-z\d])\1{3}|\d+\b)[a-z\d]+', re.IGNORECASE)
s = "df\nAll aaaaaab the best 8965\nUS issssss is 123 good \nqqqq qwerty 1 poiks\nlkjh ggggqwe 1234 aqwe iphone5224s"
strs = s.split("\n")                   
print([p.sub("", x).strip() for x in strs])
```

I just need to replace the word with the one that has removed the extra repeated alphabets. you can use this sentence as a test case:

```
سلاااااام چطووووورین؟ من خیلی گشتم ولی مثل این کیفیت اصلاااااا ندیدممممم.
```

It has to be like this:

```
سلام چطورین؟ من خیلی گشتم ولی مثل این کیفیت اصلا ندیدم
```

please consider that more than 3 repeats are not acceptable.

Comment: Maybe `re.sub(r'([^\W\d_])\1+', r'\1', s)`?

Comment: you know it works really good, the only problem is that I have no problem with repeated alphabets less or equal to two. More than two repeated alphabets are not bearable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337626/how-to-remove-any-unicode-repeating-letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'([^\W\d_])\1{2,}', r'\1', s)
```

It will replace chunks of identical consecutive letters with their single occurrence.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ALxocA/1).

**Details**

- `([^\W\d_])` - Capturing group 1: any Unicode letter
- `\1{2,}` - two or more repetitions of the same letter that is captured in Group 1.

The `r'\1'` replacement will only keep a single letter occurrence in the result.

Comment: That was a great job wiktor. The details were helpful.